# changing the id of an element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change the id of an element in jquery i.e

```
$('.aiButton').click(function(){
            $('.aiButton').id('saveold');

<a class="aiButton" id="savenew" href="login.php"><span>Save</span></a></li>
```

you see i want to chnage the id from savenew to `saveold` is this how you do it, i think this is worng thanks!!

Comment: There isn't an `id()` function.

Comment: He mentioned `i.e.` not literally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the ID, you need `$('.aiButton').attr('id', 'saveold');`, or more efficiently in this case `this.id = 'saveold'`.

Answer (score 7):

I do this:

```
$('.aiButton').click(function()
{
    // $(this).removeAttr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', 'id-name-goes-here');
});
```

Comment: `removeAttr()` is redundant if you're overwriting it.